# useCallback is not working when using with child component of same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a parent Component and a child component. And I use the child component twice in my parent component. I pass them two different state values as props and two different events as props. I have tried to memoize both the callbacks , but both the child are re-rendered even if one child callback is triggred. Why is useCallback not working.

Parent Component:

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
    import './App.css'
    import List from "./components/list";
    import LocalList from "./components/localList";

function App() {
  const itemsToBuy = [
    'Baby Shoes',
    'Grinder',
    'Car'
  ]
 
 
  const [buyList, updateBuyList] = useState(itemsToBuy);
  const [sellList, updateSellList] = useState([
    'Bed',
    'Sofa'
  ]);
  
  /** code to check the re-rendering of the componnet  */
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`parent is being rendered`)
  })

  /**trying to update the state from internal method to be passed as props */

  const updateBuyClick = useCallback(val => {
    updateBuyList(prev => [...prev, val])
  }, [buyList])

  const updateSellClick = useCallback(val => {
    console.log('memo of sell is called')
    updateSellList(prev => [...prev, val])
  }, [sellList])


  return (
    <>
      <div className='container'>
        <div>
          <h1>Items To Buy</h1>
          <List itemsArray={buyList} onUpdateClick={updateBuyClick} buttonText='Add Items to Buy' idx={'list One'}></List>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Items to Sell</h1>
          <List itemsArray={sellList} onUpdateClick={updateSellClick} buttonText='Add Items to Sell' idx={'list Two '}></List>
        </div>
        {/* <div>
          <h1>List that is not re-rendere</h1>
          <LocalList buttonText='Add Items to LocalList' idx={'list3 '}></LocalList>
        </div> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child Component:

```
import { useState , useEffect} from "react";
import './list.css'

function List({ itemsArray = [], buttonText, onUpdateClick, idx }) {
    let currentSell = '';

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`${idx} is being rendered`)
    })
    const updateCurrentSell = (val) => {
        currentSell = val;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {itemsArray.map((value, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
                })}
            </ul>

            <div>

                <input type='text' onChange={(e) => { updateCurrentSell(e.target.value) }}></input>
                <button onClick={() => { onUpdateClick(currentSell) }}>{buttonText}</button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default List;
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question, as `updateSellClick` does not appear to be used anywhere. Anyway, I think your problems are caused by having `buyList` in the dependency array to `useCallback`, this is completely unnecessary as it's not referenced in the function - in fact the function will update `buyList` so it guarantees a new function reference will be passed to the child component each time it's clicked! You can just use an empty dependency array here.

Comment: Looks like your child component changes the state of the parent component, in this case the parent will re-render (with all children).

Comment: @tromgy - True, but the children can be memoized so their render function doesn't have to run again, which is what I think the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons that's not working:

1. You're telling `useCallback` to throw away the stored copy of your function when the `buyList` or `sellList` changes by including those in your dependencies array. You don't need those dependencies, because you're (correctly) using the callback version of the state setters. So you aren't using `buyList` or `sellList` in the callbacks. Just remove them from the arrays.

   ```
   const updateBuyClick = useCallback(val => {
     updateBuyList(prev => [...prev, val])
   }, [])
   // ^^−−− empty

   const updateSellClick = useCallback(val => {
     console.log('memo of sell is called')
     updateSellList(prev => [...prev, val])
   }, [])
   // ^^−−− empty
   ```
2. `useCallback` only does half the necessary work: making sure the functions don't change unnecessarily. But your `List` component has to do the *other* half of the work: not re-rendering if its props don't change. With a function component, you do that with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

   ```
   const List = React.memo(function List({ itemsArray = [], buttonText, onUpdateClick, idx }) {
       // ...
   });
   ```

   `React.memo` *memoizes* the component and reuses its last rendering if its props don't change. (You can customize that by providing a callback as its second argument, see the documentation for details.)

Between those two changes, you'll see only the appropriate instances of `List` re-render when things change.

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } = React;

function App() {
    const itemsToBuy = [
        "Baby Shoes",
        "Grinder",
        "Car"
    ];

    const [buyList, updateBuyList] = useState(itemsToBuy);
    const [sellList, updateSellList] = useState([
        "Bed",
        "Sofa"
    ]);

    // *** Note: No need for this to be in `useEffect`
    console.log(`parent is being rendered`)

    const updateBuyClick = useCallback(val => {
        updateBuyList(prev => [...prev, val]);
    }, []);

    const updateSellClick = useCallback(val => {
        updateSellList(prev => [...prev, val])
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Items To Buy</h1>
                <List itemsArray={buyList} onUpdateClick={updateBuyClick} buttonText="Add Items to Buy" idx={"list One"}></List>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Items to Sell</h1>
                <List itemsArray={sellList} onUpdateClick={updateSellClick} buttonText="Add Items to Sell" idx={"list Two "}></List>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const List = React.memo(function List({ itemsArray = [], buttonText, onUpdateClick, idx }) {
    // *** `currentSell` stuff should be in state, not a local variable
    const [currentSell, setCurrentSell] = useState("");

    console.log(`${idx} is being rendered`);

    return (  // <>...</> is fine, I had to change it because the
            // version of Babel Stack Snippets use is out of date
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {itemsArray.map((value, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
                })}
            </ul>

            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setCurrentSell(e.target.value); }}></input>
                <button onClick={() => { onUpdateClick(currentSell); }}>{buttonText}</button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```